# How to customise appBar while using SearchDelegate Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and am working on a page that uses a Class which extends the SearchDelgate. Even though, the function I wish to implement works as I want but I dont like the looks and feel of it. The colors are all white in the AppBar. Is there a way to change the color of the background of the AppBar?

My Code is Below:

````
class doctorSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {

  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
      //somecode here
}

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
      //somecode here
   }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
//somecode here

  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
//somecode here
   }

}```
````

Comment: It would be nice if you attach code snippet that's relevant to your question so that others can start answering from there.

Comment: I have provided the code that I'm using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter provides lots of options. 
If you have an overall theme set for your entire application, then you can override `appBarTheme` to get the looks of your overall app as shown below.

```
class exampleClass extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme.of(context);
  }
.
.
.
}// end of exampleClass
```

If you would like to have a customized color for the appBar (red in this case), then inside your "SearchDelegate" extended class you can override the `appBarTheme` as below:

```
class exampleClass extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    return ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.red,
    );
  }
.
.
.
}// end of exampleClass
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you